# Setting a desired time for NSDate object fails when adding a week component to it

Tags: iphone, ios, datetime

I'm trying to schedule notifications on every 2 weeks at 12:00 (noon) by looping the following code...

```
unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;

// Allocate new temporary calendar object with default timezone
NSCalendar *tmpCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[tmpCalendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

// Allocate new temporary date components from the date to fire
NSDateComponents *tmpDateComps = [tmpCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:dateToFire];

// Set time to '12.00'
[tmpDateComps setHour:12];
[tmpDateComps setMinute:0];

// Get new date to fire object based on date components
dateToFire = [tmpCalendar dateFromComponents:tmpDateComps];

NSLog(@"dateToFire %@", dateToFire);
// On 6th iteration = xx-xx-xxxx 09:00 +00:00
// On 11th iteration = xx-xx-xxxx 10:00 +00:00

// Allocate new temporary offset date components
NSDateComponents *tmpOffsetComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];    

// Add a number of weeks
[tmpOffsetComps setWeek:2];

// Get new date to fire object based on offset date components
dateToFire = [tmpCalendar dateByAddingComponents:tmpOffsetComps toDate:dateToFire options:0];

NSLog(@"dateToFire %@", dateToFire);
//On 6th iteration = xx-xx-xxxx 10:00 +00:00
//On 11th iteration = xx-xx-xxxx 09:00 +00:00
```

Somehow when I log the `dateToFire` object inside the loop, on the 6th iteration I first get the correct `xx-xx-xxxx 09:00 +00:00` but on the second log after I've added the offset components, I get `xx-xx-xxxx 10:00 +00:00`. The strange thing is that it gets back to correct time inside 11th iteration.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this strange behavior?

**UPDATE**
As UIAdam stated, this was happening due to daylight saving so this is a normal behavior.

Comment: What does your unitFlags look like?

Comment: Do you have something equivalent to daylight savings/standard time in your location? I'm guessing that is what is adding/subtracting the extra hour. What are the actual dates it is printing when the hour changes?

Comment: You are genius! Never thought that. Times do change after october 31st and back again after march 31st. TY!

Comment: @UIAdam you okay if I delete this question?

Comment: @UIAdam & micadelli: this question/answer might help others, we often forget about daylight savings :) It would be best if UIAdam copies his comment as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I will create a real answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra hour is appearing/disappearing due to the date crossing the boundary between daylight savings/standard time (or some equivalent in your locale).